# Re-attach volume claim on deployment update

Tags: kubernetes, persistence, kubectl, volumes

I'm using persistent volume claim to store data in container:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test-pvc
  labels:
    type: amazonEBS
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

Declaration in spec:

```
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: test-data-vol
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: test-pvc
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: my.docker.registry/test:1.0
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/data
      name: test-data-vol
```

When I started it first time, this volume was mounted correctly. But when I Tried to update container image:

```
-    image: my.docker.registry/test:1.0
+    image: my.docker.registry/test:1.1
```

This volume failed to mount to new pod:

```
# kubectl get pods
test-7655b79cb6-cgn5r       0/1     ContainerCreating   0          3m
test-bf6498559-42vvb        1/1     Running             0          11m

# kubectl describe test-7655b79cb6-cgn5r
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age   From                                                  Message
  ----     ------                 ----  ----                                                  -------
  Normal   Scheduled              3m5s  default-scheduler                                     Successfully assigned test-7655b79cb6-cgn5r to ip-*-*-*-*.us-west-2.compute.internal
  Warning  FailedAttachVolume     3m5s  attachdetach-controller                               Multi-Attach error for volume "pvc-2312eb4c-c270-11e8-8d4e-065333a7774e" Volume is already exclusively attached to one node and can't be attached to another
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  3m4s  kubelet, ip-*-*-*-*.us-west-2.compute.internal  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-x82km"
  Warning  FailedMount            62s   kubelet, ip-*-*-*-*.us-west-2.compute.internal  Unable to mount volumes for pod "test-7655b79cb6-cgn5r(fab0862c-d1cf-11e8-8d4e-065333a7774e)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "test-7655b79cb6-cgn5r". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[test-data-vol]
```

It seems that Kubernetes can't re-attach this volume from one container to another. How to handle it correctly? I need this data on volume to be used by new version of deployment when old version stopped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is that EBS volumes are `ReadWriteOnce` and can only be mounted to a single pod, so when you do the rolling update the old pod holds the volume. For this to work you would either have to use [`StatefulSet`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#deployment-and-scaling-guarantees) or you can use any of the [`ReadWriteMany`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) PV types.

A [Kubernetes Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) is sometimes better used for stateless pods.

You can always go with the brute force approach which force delete the pod that is holding the volume. Make sure that the [`Reclaim Policy`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#reclaim-policy) is set to `Retain`.

Comment: Thanks, I've replaced `Deployment` with `StatefulSet` and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 12):

From the context you provided in your question, I can't tell if your intention was to run a **single instance** stateful application, or a **clustered** stateful application.

I ran into this problem recently and from [this section in the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/#updating), here's how to go about this...

**If you're running a single instance stateful app:**

- You should **not** scale the app, that is, leave the default value of `spec.replicas` as 1 if you're using a `Deployment`
- You should instruct Kubernetes to **not** use rolling updates, that is, you should set `spec.strategy.type` to `Recreate` in your `Deployment`

Sample `Deployment` (from the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/#deploy-mysql)):

```
# application/mysql/mysql-deployment.yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.6
        name: mysql
        env:
          # Use secret in real usage
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

And the sample `PersistentVolume` & `PersistentVolumeClaim` (from the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/#deploy-mysql)):

```
# application/mysql/mysql-pv.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
```

The obvious underlying matter here is that a rolling update will not work, because there can be no more than one pod running at any time. Setting `spec.strategy.type` to `Recreate` tells Kubernetes to stop the running pod before deploying a new one, so presumably there will be some downtime, even if minimal.

**If you need a clustered stateful application**, then using the already mentioned `StatefulSet` as a controller type or `ReadWriteMany` as a storage type would probably be the way to go.

Comment: This is the correct answer if you want to have a single persistent volume and don't need to scale your app. StatefulSets create a persistent volume per replica, which allows both persistence and scaling.

Comment: This helped as apparently on azure aks ReadWriteMany is not supported yet :'( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/974276/aks-k8s-doesn39t-supports-new-keyword-readwriteonc.html